# startActivityForResult is now deprecated, can someone find me an alternative for voice search?

Tags: java, voice-recognition, voice, startactivityforresult

I'm using startActivityForResult function in my voice search method but unfortunately it's now deprecated, can someone help met to get a solution for this problem and also I got few errors that I don't know how to solve it.

here is my code
[image: Code for voice search in android studio using java]

I hope someone can help me solve this by sending an alternative code for my method using java

Answer (score 1):

```
you can see from the example here. If there is something you don't understand, please reply


binding.imageBookAdmin.setOnClickListener {
        ImagePicker.with(this)
            .compress(1024)
            .galleryOnly()
            .createIntent {intent->
                startForPostPictureResult.launch(intent)
            }
    }

private val startForPostPictureResult =registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){ result: ActivityResult ->
    when (result.resultCode) {
        Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
            imageUri = result.data?.data!!
            binding.imageBookAdmin.setImageURI(imageUri)
        }
        getStorageImage.error -> {
            toast("${result.data}")
        }
        else -> {
            Log.d("PostFragment", "Get Image Cancelled")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private val startForPostPictureResult =registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){result:ActivityResult->
    when (result.resultCode) {
        Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
            
        }
        getStorageImage.error -> {
            
        }
        else -> {
            
        }
    }
}
```

If you want, you can see an example in the Kotlin programming language. I think it should be done in Java

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).